# Why Visual Studio's console disappear?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console-application

**Case 1:** With this normal case, the console is **appear**.

```
int main() {
    string s4(4,'a');
    string s3(3, 'b');

    cout << s3+s4<<endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Case 2:** I add a `cin >>` and the console get **disappear**, why ?

```
int main() {
    string s4(4,'a');
    string s3(3, 'b');
    string word;
    cin >> word;
    cout << s3+s4+word <<endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Case 3:** I add one more `cin.get()` and the console get **appear** again, why ?

```
int main() {
    string s4(4,'a');
    string s3(3, 'b');
    string word;
    cin >> word;
    cout << s3+s4+word <<endl;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is that there're characters left in the input buffer (in your example a newline character).

The first `cin.get()` in **case 3** reads the `\n` and the second one waits for a new character.

`std::cin` is notorious at causing input issues because it doesn't remove the newline character from the stream.

Also, reading strings, it will break on a space: if you enter something that is more than a single word, only the first word is going to be loaded (leaving the space and following words still in the input stream).

To extract entire lines of text, the string overload of the global function [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is a better option.

---

You shouldn't add "tricky" commands to keep the console open (`cin.get()`, `system("pause")`...): hereafter you'll have to remember to remove them from the "production" code.

You can run your program *Without debugger mode* (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) and Visual Studio will keep the console application window open until you press a button (just check the settings in `Project -> Properties -> Linker -> System -> Sub System -> Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`).

Of course, if you are debugging (<kbd>F5</kbd>), a breakpoint on the `return 0;` is the best option.